# How does ElasticSearch handle the new requests?

Tags: elasticsearch

Different types of database servers (or any server for that matter) handle requests differently. For instance, Redis use an Event loop, Postgres spawns up a new process to handle a new request, etc. How does ES do it?

1. By creating a new thread?
2. By creating a new process?
3. By Event loop?
4. Any other mechanism?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, it creates a new thread so it's not recommended to let many clients connect directly to the ES node at the same time. If you have multiple clients it is recommended to  set up a load balancer in front of the ES cluster to limit number of connections and round-robin clients between nodes.

Comment: ilvar, can you please refer me to some documentation or piece of code about this thread creation part as well as any doc which tells about this load balancer setup? Couldn't find any.

Comment: It's not documented and I can't find the specific code snippet, just based on my experience: ES performance degrades significantly when there are hundreds of clients connected at once.